# Android RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout?

Tags: android

I have the following code for a RecyclerView:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
    return new HomeFragment();
}

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private PostAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.home_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        postList.add(new Post(1, new JSONObject("{}"), new ArrayList<Bitmap>()));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mAdapter = new PostAdapter(postList);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}

}
```

This produces the error:
`E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` even though there is clearly an adapter attached to the RecyclerView. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)

Comment: @KeLiuyue doesn't work, same error produced

Comment: are you setting the adapter in the ui/main thread?

Comment: @Sony it's called in the onCreateView inside of a fragment. Is this off the main thread?

Comment: no, it is on the main thread,

Comment: try creating the adapter first and then set the adapter and then set the layout manager

Comment: @Sony that's the way I have the code now and it doesn't work. The order doesn't seem to matter

Comment: show the complete activity code or at least onCreate method

Comment: are you using another recyclerview to show the arraylist of bitmaps?

Comment: @NoumanCh edited post with full Fragment snippet

Comment: @Sony the array list of BitMaps is irrelevant right now, nothing shows in the RecyclerView no matter what the data is. All of the PostAdapter methods never get called.

Comment: can you post your adapter code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
```

instead of this you must do

```
return view;
```

Comment: All too simple. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, I got it. I felt really stupid after looking at it.

Comment: you are improving your self don't worry. keep working.